# creating table in php mysql with quotation

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a php mysql query through

```
 mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `user` (`id` NOT NULL INT,`username`  VARCHAR(30),`password`  VARCHAR(30))");
```

it gives me error

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL INT,`username`  VARCHAR(30),`password`  VARCHAR(30))'
```

I am new to php mysql how I can fix this syntax?

Comment: You should state the field type first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `user` (`id` INT NOT NULL ,`username`  VARCHAR(30),`password`  VARCHAR(30))");
```

not:

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `user` (`id` NOT NULL INT,`username`  VARCHAR(30),`password`  VARCHAR(30))");
```

By the way, don't use mysql_ functions they are deprecated, and in future versions of php they will get removed. Use mysqli_ instead, using them is almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

From [**the doc**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    [(create_definition,...)]
    ...

create_definition:
    col_name column_definition
    ...

column_definition:
    data_type [NOT NULL | NULL]
      [DEFAULT default_value]
      [AUTO_INCREMENT] [UNIQUE [KEY] | [PRIMARY] KEY]
      ...

data_type:
    BIT[(length)]
    ...
  | INT[(length)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
```

In other words, `INT` (or any *datatype definition*) should always precede `NOT NULL` (or `NULL`) *modifier*. In fact, that's true for any modifiers - `DEFAULT`, `AUTO_INCREMENT`, `UNIQUE` and so on.

---

As a sidenote, even though you're making first steps in PHP-MySQL, I'd recommend you start learning either [**mysqli**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extensions - these are a bit more sophisticated than [**mysql**](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), but it's worth it.

Getting into mysql extension *in 2014* will be a waste of time - it's deprecated for quite a long time already. Here's what's said on its `intro` page:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended
>   for writing new code as it will be removed in the future.